# Way to place border for images in listview

Tags: android

I have listview and i have got set of images in a row. I would like to add border for images what is the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

put this with in drawable folder with name image_border.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#8d8d8d" />
        <padding 
            android:left="1dip" 
            android:top="1dip"
            android:right="1dip" 
            android:bottom="1dip" />
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    </shape>
```

and use attributes `android:background="@drawable/image_border"` for ImageView

You can change the shape according your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I got your Question
Now If you have ImageView in Your XML file then you also have this below code:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 

    />
```

So add below line in your imageView tag:

```
          android:background="@drawable/Imagexml" 
           android:padding="6dp"
```

Now as in android:background there is Imagexml.xml file in drawable folder .

The Imagexml.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#0079AD"
            android:endColor="#009AD6"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#F1FAFE" />
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#007900"
            android:startColor="#009A77"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#F1FAFE" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#0079AD"
            android:startColor="#009AD6"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#F1FAFE" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then you will get the result as you want.